# Regular Expression for Removing (nested) Parentheses

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring

I am using DOM to get a Wikipedia article as a NSString and then using NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range: to remove unneeded things. I'm using regular expressions, which I don't have much experience with. From reading Apple's documentation and just trying things I was able to make this

```
"\\[[\\w]+\\]"
```

regular expression which removes the brackets from the Wikipedia article. This works perfectly fine because brackets aren't nested.

Now I am trying to remove parentheses (including everything inside them (and nested ones)) from the NSString. I'm having problems with the nesting part. With this

```
\\s+\\([^\\)]*+\\)
```

regular expression I was able to remove a set of parentheses including the space before it (so I don't end up with duplicate spaces after is removed). What regular expression could I use to do this same thing but also remove nested parentheses instead?

My current implementation will change this

> The quick brown (slightly reddish) fox jumped over the lazy (he was old (26 years) and exhausted) dog.

into this

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy and exhausted) dog.

while the desired result is this

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Comment: Try this: remove the [^\\)]* and write .* instead to enable the * operator to be greedy. If that doesn't work, it's probably not possible to solve this using purely regexes.

Comment: "\\s+\\(*+\\)" resulted in just the original expression, "The quick brown (slightly reddish) fox jumped over the lazy (he was old (26) and exhausted) dog."

Comment: Don't try to "parse" Wikipedia page sources. They have a [excellent api](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Api) to get the rendered content.

Comment: Regular Expressions are generally not suitable for "parsing" of nested grammars.

Comment: Here is how I figure it would work: 1. Find open parenthesis. 2. Continue until next open parenthesis. 3. If there was a close parenthesis between those two open parenthesis, end finding at the close parenthesis with the highest index. If no close parenthesis is found, repeat step 2 and 3.

Comment: The second possible solution I can think of is this: Look for the innermost parentheses with the regular expression by disallowing other parentheses between them. Repeat this until no parentheses are present.

Comment: Both of these would fail, however, if the article was about parentheses and mentioned them like this "(" because it would remove them incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. This method will return the string without nested parentheses.

```
-(NSString*)stringWithoutParentheses:(NSString*)input{
     NSString *expression = @"\\s+\\([^()]*\\)";
     while ([input rangeOfString:expression options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location!=NSNotFound)
     {
          input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:expression withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
     }
     return input;
}
```

With this method, passing

> The quick brown (slightly reddish) fox jumped over the lazy (he was old (26) and exhausted) dog.

will return

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Comment: The explanation about this expression is that it removes inner parenthesis only, but repeats the operation until there is no more matching parenthesis.